# Internal Storage does not have a drive name

Tags: storage, mobile-phone

The internal storage of my phone shows up as:

```
Computer\Xperia SL\Internal Storage
```

Hence I am unable to copy the entire contents of the drive using either `Fastcopy` or `CMD`

Why is it that it does not have a drive name, like F: or G: or whatever.

Basically I want to copy all the files and folders from the Computer\Xperia SL\Internal Storage to a folder on E: drive. Using Explorer it was taking a long time, I read here that fastcopy helps, but the Internal Storage is just not showing up in fast copy. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

In order to assign a drive letter to a removable device, that device must support UMS (USB Mass Storage) protocol. Unfortunately some phones, especially those without a removable SD Card, do not support UMS. Instead, they support MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) and PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol) protocols. In such devices it's not possible to map storage as a drive in Windows.

Suggestions on how to fix this include:

Using Windows Mobile Developer Power Toys: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10601 with a command similar to:

> cecopy file.exe dev:\file.exe

Enable USB Mass Storage Mode:  Although this isnt included by default on the experia series (no idea why!), you can do it by installing an app according to this article:
http://www.xda-developers.com/android/mass-storage-mode-for-sony-xperia-s-p-and-u/

Although I am unable to verify this as I have neither the time or an experia handset!

Edit: on further research, I've found this link which suggests it may be possible to enable USB Mass Storage After all: http://www.device-recovery.com/how-to-connect-android-devices-to-pc-with-usb-mass-storage-mode

Hope this helps